# Memory leaks after finishing activity

Tags: android, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, android-activity

I think some of my activitys within my app are leaking memory. I tried following:
Activity A is the launcher-activiy and takes ~23,5MB total memory (dalvik+native).
When I start activity B from A my app takes about 4 more MB (~27,5MB). If I start activity C from A my app takes about 4 more MB (~27,5MB), too. Thus, if I start both activitys about 7 MBs are taken (~30,5MB). 
Now I'm doing following:
A->start B from A-> start C from B-> finish B. The expected amount of memory which is additionally taken is about 4MBs (~27,5MB), but my app actually consumes overall 7 more MBs (~30,5MB). Why does this happen?

thx & regards

PS: I'm using Little Eye to analyse the memory usage of my app. All data are representing total memory-values (dalvik + native).
If I just do A->start B from A-> finish B no memory is released after step 3.

Comment: Use MAT to identify actual memory leaks.

Answer (score 3):

You can't force the garbage collector to collect memory in any way. finish() simply tells the system that the activity has finished and results can be propagated back.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29

Try forcing the garbage collector with System.gc() but, again, this doesn't guarantee that memory will be garbage collected even when no living reference to the object exists.
Try looking here:

http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html

Also, memory leak in a garbage collected environment means that an object can't be garbage collected because a pending reference is still pointing to it. If this may be your case try using the Eclipse plugin MAT.

Comment: But how can I figure out if it is a matter of memory-leaks or just uncollected memory?
       Should I do sth like that:
'A->heap Dump h1-> start B from A-> finish B-> heap Dump h2' 
     And then compare h2 to h1. Can I say that , if there is an excess of instances, memory is leaked and if not the memory is just not garbage collected yet?

Comment: Use MAT to see which objects has living references when they shouldn't. This identifies a memory leak for you. There are many ways to improve the memory usage and MAT is one of the tools who helps you achieve that. Study some references about profiling and try it.